# Batch - copy folder to many folders using wildcard

Tags: windows, batch-file

I’m trying to copy a subfolder of one folder into a number of other folders with unknown names. The intention ist to backup the source file of a program in all employees folders who use it. If the programs folder isn’t found in an employees folder, nothing should be done. This looks as follows:

Source:

> ```
> F:\Users\myFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder
> ```

Target:

> ```
> F:\Users\anotherOnesFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder
> ```

So my idea was to do the following:

```
xcopy "F:\Users\myFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" "F:\Users\*\programFolder\Sourcefolder" /e /y
```

But this wildcard doesn’t seem to work. I’ve found a lot about wildcards at the end of the path, but that doesn’t apply here.

Comment: Your `xcopy` command line should work when using `XXcopy` from  http://www.xxcopy.com which has improved wildcard handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d %%d in ("F:\Users\*") do (
    if /i not "%%~nxd"=="myFolder" if exist "%%~fd\folder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" ( 
        robocopy  "F:\Users\myFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" "%%~fd\folder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" * /mir
    )
)
```

Comment: Please provide more details of what are you suggesting.

Comment: For each directory in f:\Users, if the name and extension of selected folder does not match the source folder (to not copy source to source), and destination directory exists (only copy if the user has it), then mirror source to target.

Comment: With a little modification this has done the job, thanks! I had to remove the "\folder" to make it work. So the final (working) lines of code are:                                                     for /d %%d in ("F:\Users\*") do ( if /i not "%%~nxd"=="myFolder" if exist "%%~fd\programFolder\Sourcefolder" ( robocopy "F:\Users\myFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" "%%~fd\programFolder\Sourcefolder" * /mir ) )                               Note: "F:\Users\*" shows up wrong here and in the OP. It must be (without spaces) "F:\Users \ *"

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %a in ('dir /ad /b "F:\Users*"') do (
 xcopy  F:\Users\myFolder\programFolder\Sourcefolder "%~dpfa\folder\programFolder\Sourcefolder" /e /y
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I didn't check this version as the other one already solved my problem.